# Show 100K results of complex query on map without using graphics?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geoprocessing

- I need to show all 100K points on the map without using any sort of clustering.
- Since they are too much they cannot be shown using a graphics layer.
- since they are result of a very complex Oracle text query in cannot be applied in a dynamic layer.
- The only way to show so much graphics on a may is via an image since the DOM can't stand that much graphics.

So, to sum up, I want to:
(Apply a complex query and get 100K points) --> (pass the IDs or lat/lon in a service) ---> get the generated image layer

Any suggested solutions ? (ORACLE 12g, ArcGis 10.2)

Answer (score 1):

Try to build a geoprocessing service tool with Result map service option.

First connect to database and execute in arcpy and get the IDs. Pass into second service and generate the layer as image. 
You can use python scripts to implement this.

Comment: If you generate the layer as image, will that be working as a dynamic map service (pan, zoom map in the front end) ?  Also, have you got any idea about the performance implications of such a solution ?

Comment: I think you do not have better option, If you make it as result map service,every map update it will generate new image and send to the client. I need to know that every map update you need to execute the query? Otherwise think about another approach to optimize the query optimization. Can you explain more about this problem?

Comment: No I wont have to rerun the query. I will run the station search query once using JAVA/ Oracle Text  so a to get my points (100K). These points should be projected on the map. So It should be considered a separate task to search for resuts and then to use the results so as to create a feature class shown with a map service. So the steps are: 1)Peform search in UI 2) Web server executes query/gets results/creates json/ passess json to GP task  3) Gp task only creates featureclass from json and returns a map service URL !! FOR THE SPECIFIC SEARCH!!!

Comment: Mak your GP task as a Result Map Service mode. refer http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//0057000000m7000000